# Opened network ports, safe or not?

Tags: macos, network, router

I check my opened ports via **Network Utility** (macOS X High Sierra 10.3.3) and get this result:

Port Scanning host: MY EXTERNAL IP

```
 Open TCP Port:     21          ftp
 Open TCP Port:     23          telnet
 Open TCP Port:     80          http
 Open TCP Port:     1900        ssdp
 Open TCP Port:     5916
 Open TCP Port:     7547        cwmp
 Open TCP Port:     20005
 Open TCP Port:     33344
 Open TCP Port:     56614
```

But if I try to check the same ports *online*, through a website port checker tool on my external ip, the result is all these ports **closed** or **connection timed out**... what is the difference? so what is the REAL result for my TP-LINK router and system? are these ports safe, if opened? and generally which are the only ones safe (if opened) for macos X?

Comment: Are you on your local network when you check your ports?  You can't scan your external network ports from inside the same network.  You might have those ports open on your Mac (as reported by Network Utility) but your firewall/router has those ports closed.  Now, as to those particular ports - ***why, oh why, do you have ftp and telnet enabled???  They are horribly insecure.  You should be using ssh (port 22) instead.***

Comment: Oh yes @Allan, I'm on my local network (internal address 192.168.X.XXX, even if I scanned my external ip address), so the REAL result is the website port checker tool? About ftp and telnet enabled I think its a function of TP-LINK Router (USB port in the back, and storage across the network)

Comment: Those are the management ports on your firewall.  It has two IPs (the public and the private).  If you attempt to connect to it via the public IP, it will not go out, circle back, and then connect, it will connect to the private side.  What these results are telling you is that those ports are open *inside* your network and closed *outside*.   That said...they're still insecure.  Both results are correct - outside is closed, inside they're open.

Comment: Ok, so in this situation a security problem is still possible from INSIDE my home network, or if someone is able to enter into from external, I suppose. Now my problem is to understand what softwares are using these internal ports and the way to eventually close them

Comment: Yes to both counts.  If you decide to enable WAN management, you expose your router.  The OS on the router is what uses those ports.  You have the option to turn them on/off.

Comment: Please note that the results you have got might not be reliable. Check with "netstat -anv |grep LISTEN" on macOS to see if you actually have programs listening on ports 21, 23, etc. In some cases, ISPs are known to actually "simulate" that you have these ports open when port scanning your external IP. In reality they are just trapping those ports and making sure anyone trying to connect are just timed out/connection hung. In reality blocking all their customers from exposing ports 21, 23 and similar to the outside world.

Comment: Hey @jksoegaard netstat command give me only 3 results with LISTEN: tcp6 and tcp4 on port *.49162 and tcp4 in port 127.0.0.1.49152. If I use lsof command it give me PID for rapportd and coreaudio. What is the point? The only ports now opened (or listening) on my MAC SYSTEM are 49152 and 49162?